# Letter with address in the Margin

Tags: margins, letters

I'd like to format a letter in line with this image:[image: Layout-grid]

Instead of the usual three-part layout with Header, main body, and footer, I'd like to split it up into four parts:

- Header and footer across the whole width of the text-area, with (say) 1" margins
- the main body text indented further, say, by an extra 2"
- A textbox left-aligned under the header that contains the address and date information from the letter.

I tried using the `geometry` package but could not figure out how to adjust only the margins of the main body without also affecting the header and footer (ignorehead option gave no joy).

Comment: This looks like a job for flowfram (no fancyhdr needed).

Comment: A quick thought: fiddling with the `tufte-latex` package might do the trick. You would just need to put the address as a margin note and force margin notes on the left.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably not the most elegant solution, but it's relatively simple.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[letterpaper,reversemp,right=1in,top=1in,textwidth=26pc,marginparwidth=12pc,marginparsep=2pc,includemp]{geometry}
\fancyhfoffset[RE,LO]{\marginparsep+\marginparwidth}
\fancyhead{\textsc{this \hfill is a header}}
\fancyfoot{\textsc{this \hfill is a footer}}



\begin{document}
    \thispagestyle{fancy}

\reversemarginpar\marginpar{\textsf{Some University}%
\par\textsf{A small department}%
\par\textsf{Back alley}%
\par\textsf{Small Town, NW 55555}}%

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

\end{document}
```

[image]